# How can I compute the minimum no. of replacements to convert a string to make a palindrome?

Tags: string, dynamic-programming, palindrome

The question states to convert a string to a palindrome by replacing the characters in the string.
The length of the palindrome string formed must be same as the original string.

For Example: a string abcde, to convert to a palindrome,

min replacements: 2

abcde -> abcba

And what if it requires a specific substring to be part of the resultant palindromic string?

Example: string requires substring "tea" to be part of resultant string

then abcdef -> aettea

min replacement : 4

Answer (score 0):

Palindromes by definition are alike on each side of their center point.

For a string with odd letters, the max length of the string minus one and divided by two will give you the number of characters to replace.

```
(length - 1) / 2 = #charsReplaced
```

For even lengthed string, the max length of replaced characters is the length divided by two.

```
length / 2 = #charsReplaced
```

Finding the minimum number of chars to replace would require reading in the string by each char, mapping the chars on each side of the center point on the string, and determining which ones are alike. For each that already have a similar letter on each side (e.g., abcbe has 1 less than the max), you separate that amount from the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

It's a logical problem, but I think you can compute it by using this algorithm I devised:

read the string ex: abcde

get the first half (ab)

check the reverse of the other half if that matches your first half (is ab equal to de?)

count the unequal characters

answer = 2

example: radaa
firsthalf: ra
check reverse of the other half: aa
match if equal: ra = aa
count the number of unequal characters: 1
replace: a = r
then you got your result: radar, 1 character flaw.